# How to replace blanks (“”) in certain columns (specifically, “NAICSP” and “SOCP”) with NA values

Tags: r, na, missing-data

In RStudio. Not sure how to replace blanks from certain columns only - and based on their names. 
Have tried many version of

```
census_data[c("NAICSP","SOCP") == ""] <- NA
```

Comment: Hi Dianna Li. By adding a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)you can help others to help you! You  said you tried "many versions" : Have you tried `census_data[census_data$NAICSP %in% "", "NAICSP"] <- NA` ? What was the output?

Comment: Replaces all blanks in the file, instead of just the two columns.

Comment: Edit: That actually worked. Looked at the wrong columns. However, I'm not familiar with what the $ and %in% portions do.

Comment: Current Code: 
census_data[census_data$NAICSP %in% "", "NAICSP"] <- NA
census_data[census_data$SOCP %in% "", "SOCP"] <- NA

Answer (score 2):

You may try using `apply` in column mode, for a base R option:

```
cols <- c("NAICSP","SOCP")
census_data[, cols] <- apply(census_data[, cols], 2, function(x) {
    ifelse(x == "", NA, x)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This answer uses [mde](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/mde), a package that I happen to have written. If one is open to using packages, one can use `recode_as_na` from `mde` and provide a `subset_cols` vector as follows:

```
census_data<- data.frame(ID = c("A","B","B","A"),
                         NAICSP = c("",NA,"Yes","No"),
                          SOCP = c("","","",""))
 # install.packages("devtools")
 # devtools::install_github("Nelson-Gon/mde")
 mde::recode_as_na(census_data,subset_df=TRUE,
                   subset_cols = c("NAICSP","SOCP"),
                   value="")
  ID NAICSP SOCP
1  A   <NA>   NA
2  B   <NA>   NA
3  B    Yes   NA
4  A     No   NA
Warning message:
In recode_as_na.data.frame(census_data, subset_df = TRUE, subset_cols = c("NAICSP",  :
  Factor columns have been converted to character
```

**NOTE**:

The warning message is to remind users of behind the scenes coercion to character.